# Is Frobenius on $R^\circ/p$ surjective for general perfectoid rings $R$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

In [1], Propisition 6.1.9(2), it said that if $R$ is a perfectoid ring such that $pR^\circ$ is closed in $R^\circ$ (this includes the case if $R$ is of character $p$, or if $p$ is invertible in $R$, in particular if $R$ is a perfectoid $K$-algebra, $K$ a field), then the Frobenius $\Phi:R^\circ/p\to R^\circ/p$ is surjective (it is easy to see that this is equivalent to $R^{\flat\circ}\to R^\circ/p$ is surjective because $R^{\flat\circ}=\varprojlim R^\circ/p$). In [1], Remark 6.1.10 it said that probably $pR^\circ$ is not closed in general.

However, in the proof of [1], Lemma 6.2.7, it makes the extensive use of the surjectivity of thie map $R^{\flat\circ}\to R^\circ/p$ (say, by choosing $R^+$ to be $R^\circ$), <s>and all subsequent development of the theory relies on this lemma</s>.

So my problem is: is this map surjective in general (i.e. when $pR^\circ$ is not closed)? I noticed that in the video of Scholze's fall 2014 course he said that this is surjective without giving details. Is it wrong, or still open, or I missed something obvious? Thanks in advance.

[1] Peter Scholze's lectures on $p$-adic geometry, fall 2014

Comment: Your final question is affirmative (i.e., you have missed something obvious): this is an exercise in successive approximation since the closedness hypothesis on $pR^0$ and the completeness of $R$ ensure that $R^0/p R^0$ is the inverse limit of its quotients $R^0/(p, \varpi^{np})R^0$ for any pseudo-uniformizer $\varpi$ and we know that Frobenius is surjective on $R^0/\varpi^p R^0$ when $\varpi$ is chosen so that $\varpi^p|p$ in $R^0$.

Comment: @user74230 Thanks, but I already know that it is true if $pR^\circ$ is closed, it is proved in [1], Prop. 6.1.9. I have edited my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Probably this question is no longer interesting to the author. But since I faced the same problem while trying to learn basics of perfectoid spaces I decided to write down an argument here]

We start with a perfectoid ring $R$ and a pseudo-uniformizer $\varpi$ s.t. $\varphi:R^{\circ}/\varpi \to R^{\circ}/\varpi^p$ is surjective. This means that for any element $x\in R^{\circ}$ there is a pair of power-bounded elements $x_0, y_1$ s.t. $x=x_0^p+\varpi^py_1$. Apply the same procedure to $y_1$ to get $x_1,y_2\in R^{\circ}$ s.t. 
$$
x=x_0^p+\varpi^p(x_1^p+\varpi^py_2)=x_0^p+\varpi^px_1^p+\varpi^{2p}y_2.
$$

Keep going to obtain $x_1,\dots, x_n, y_{n+1}\in R^{\circ}$ s.t.
$$
x=x_0^p+\varpi^px_1^p+\varpi^{2p}x_2^p+\dots+\varpi^{np}x_n^p+\varpi^{(n+1)p}y_{n+1}.
$$
This implies that 
$$
x-(x_0^p+\varpi^px_1^p+\varpi^{2p}x_2^p+\dots+\varpi^{np}x_n^p)\in \varpi^{(n+1)p}R^{\circ}.
$$
Now note that since $R$ is a uniform Tate ring, so the induced topology on $R^{\circ}$ is just $\varpi$-adic topology and $R^{\circ}$ is complete with respect to this topology. Therefore, we can conclude that
$$
x=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\varpi^{ip}x_i^p.
$$
The last thing to observe is that 
$$
x-(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \varpi^{i}x_i)^p= \sum_M \varpi^M \Big(\sum_N \sum_{k_0+\dots k_N=p, k_N\geq 1, k_n\neq p, k_1+2k_2+\dots+Nk_N=M} \prod_{t=1}^N \frac{p!}{k_0!\dots k_N!}x_t^{k_t}\Big)\in pR^{\circ}.
$$
So we are done.

[To rigorously prove that this sum makes sense and lies inside $pR^{\circ}$ note that each sum in parentheses is actually finite and each of $\frac{p!}{k_0!\dots k_N!}$ is divisible by $p$ in $\mathbf Z$ (under the assumption that $k_N\geq 1$ and $k_N\neq p$). Let's say that $\frac{p!}{k_0!\dots k_N!}=pc_{k_0,\dots, k_N}$ for some integer $c_{k_0,\dots, k_N}$. Then we have 
$$
\sum_M \varpi^M \Big(\sum_N \sum_{k_0+\dots k_N=p, k_N\geq 1, k_n\neq p, k_1+2k_2+\dots+Nk_N=M} \prod_{t=1}^N \frac{p!}{k_0!\dots k_N!}x_t^{k_t}\Big)=
$$
$$
x-(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \varpi^{i}x_i)^p=p\bigg(\sum_M \varpi^M \Big(\sum_N \sum_{k_0+\dots k_N=p, k_N\geq 1, k_n\neq p, k_1+2k_2+\dots+Nk_N=M} \prod_{t=1}^N c_{k_0,\dots, k_N}x_t^{k_t}\Big)\bigg) \in pR^{\circ}.]
$$